# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, error-handling

So I wanna take the URL string and turn it into a hyperlink that has the name "play" which will take users to the video website link.

This is the class of my video links.

```
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Video_name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date added")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Dateadded { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Visits")]
    public int Video_Visits { get; set; } 
    public string URL { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parental Rating")]
    public string Parental_rating { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Rating { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Rating Rating1 { get; set; }
    public virtual P_rating P_rating  { get; set; }

}
```

In my view I add

```
<a href="@testing2.Models.Video.URL">play</a>
```

but getting the error:

> Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'testing2.Models.Video.URL.get'
>   c:\Users\Setup\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\testing2\testing2\Views\Video1\Index.cshtml 65 23
>   testing2

Anybody able to help?

Comment: It would be good if you share your complete View code

Answer (score 0):

set Video class as your model in view page.

and your link will be as

```
<a href="@Model.URL">play</a>
```

Comment: It already. You mean this piece of code at the top right? @model IEnumerable<testing2.Models.Video>

Comment: @model testing2.Models.Video    if only single record.